Problem in getting YouTube Player Elements
This is in my manifest.json file (for the purposes of a chrome extension):
    "content_scripts": [ {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "matches": ["https://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "js": ["src/contentScript.js"]
    } ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [
          "assets/youtube.png",
          "youtube.png",
          "contentScript.js"
        ],
        "matches": ["https://*.youtube.com/*"]
      }

This is in my content scripts file:
 const newVideoLoaded = async () => { 
        const askButtonExists = document.querySelector(".ytp-button.question-btn"); 

        if (!askButtonExists) {
          const button = document.createElement("img"); 
    
          button.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("../assets/youtube.png");  
          button.className = "ytp-button.question-btn";
          button.title = "Click to Ask Questions";
    
          youtubeControlBar = null; 
          youtubePlayer = null; 

          document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { // waiting for fully loaded page
            youtubeControlBar = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-left-controls")[0];
            youtubePlayer = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];
            console.log(youtubeControlBar, youtubePlayer);
          });

          if (youtubeControlBar && youtubePlayer) {
            youtubeControlBar.appendChild(button); 
            button.addEventListener("click", addButtonHandler);
      
          } else {
            console.error("YouTube control bar or player not found");
          }
        }
    };

I am running the chrome extension (locally) and the chrome extension's console shows the control bar and the player are undefined. However, when I run getElementsByClassName() in the YouTube console independently it runs just fine.
I have tried looking on Stack Overflow - and have tried some solutions, but none seem to be working.
Any help would be appreciated!
I tried various solutions from this link specifically - Access variables and functions defined in page context from an extension
None seemed to be working. Expected to actually get the YouTube player, but they are undefined. I need these elements so we can pause/play the video through our extension.

Use mutatationObserver and detect changes to DOM and react accordingly.


const newVideoLoaded = async () => { 
    const askButtonExists = document.querySelector(".ytp-button.question-btn"); 

    if (!askButtonExists) {
        const button = document.createElement("img"); 
        button.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("../assets/youtube.png");
        button.className = "ytp-button question-btn";
        button.title = "Click to Ask Questions";

        const appendButton = () => {
            const youtubeControlBar = document.getElementsByClassName("ytp-left-controls")[0];
            const youtubePlayer = document.getElementsByClassName('video-stream')[0];

            if (youtubeControlBar && youtubePlayer) {
                youtubeControlBar.appendChild(button); 
                button.addEventListener("click", addButtonHandler);
                console.log("Button added to YouTube control bar");
            } else {
                console.error("YouTube control bar or player not found");
            }
        };

        const observer = new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
            for (const mutation of mutationsList) {
                if (mutation.type === 'childList' || mutation.type === 'subtree') {
                    appendButton();
                }
            }
        });
        observer.observe(document.body, { childList: true, subtree: true });       
        appendButton();
    }
};

newVideoLoaded();



